# ERROR: debug is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am just learning Ansible with playbooks using the examples provided by Ansible.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/tree/master/lamp_simple

When I tried to put a debug message on start of the playbook, I am getting the error as given below.

```
vagrant@packer-debian-7:~/ansible-examples-master/lamp_simple$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --private-key=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -vvvv
ERROR: debug is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook
```

[site.yml]

```
---
# This playbook deploys the whole application stack in this site.  

- debug: msg="Start KickAsssss"

- name: apply common configuration to all nodes
  hosts: all

  roles:
    - common

- name: configure and deploy the webservers and application code
  hosts: webservers

  roles:
    - web

- name: deploy MySQL and configure the databases
  hosts: dbservers

  roles:
    - db
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible doesn't know which host to execute `debug` against.

Your playbook's tasks should be in a `tasks` block:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="Start KickAsssss"
```

See [Intro to Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html) for more details and examples.